# Refresh sub tab when open It

Tags: lightning-aura-components, quickaction, refresh, workspaceapi

I have a quick action button on Opportunity that called *Create Offers* which call a Lightning Component that create Offers and open the related list(Offers__r) in a sub tab.

This code working, but there is one problem: if the sub tab of the related list is already opened, this will only set the focus on it without refresh. So I will not see the newly created Offers.

Question: Is it possible to add parameter to the  *openSubtab* function to automatically refresh it?
if no how could I handle this ?

```
   openRelatedOffersSubTab: function (component) {
        debugger;
        var workspaceAPI = component.find("workspace");
        workspaceAPI.getFocusedTabInfo().then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            return response.tabId;
        }).then(function (enclosingTabId) {
            workspaceAPI.openSubtab({
                parentTabId: enclosingTabId,
                focus: true,
                pageReference: {
                    "type": "standard__recordRelationshipPage",
                    "attributes": {
                        "recordId": component.get("v.recordId"),
                        "objectApiName": "Opportunity",
                        "relationshipApiName": "Offers__r",
                        "actionName": "view"
                    }
                }
            }).then(function (subtabId) {
                console.log("The new subtab ID is:" + subtabId);
            }).catch(function (error) {
                console.log("error");
            });
        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

I tried using *refreshTab* function, without success...

```
   openRelatedOffersSubTab: function (component) {

    debugger;
    var workspaceAPI = component.find("workspace");
    workspaceAPI.getFocusedTabInfo().then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        return response.tabId;
    }).then(function (enclosingTabId) {
        workspaceAPI.openSubtab({
            parentTabId: enclosingTabId,
            pageReference: {
                "type": "standard__recordRelationshipPage",
                "attributes": {
                    "recordId": component.get("v.recordId"),
                    "objectApiName": "Opportunity",
                    "relationshipApiName": "Offers__r",
                    "actionName": "view"
                }
            }
        }).then(function (subtabId) {
            debugger;
            console.log("The new subtab ID is:" + subtabId);
            workspaceAPI.refreshTab({
                tabId: focusedTabId,
                includeAllSubtabs: true
            }).catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });}
```